# Download two images from different URL in the same activity with Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I have an activity and I want to download two images, from two different URL's in it. Do I have to make two instances of the Picasso?

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

And:

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load("http://my_photo.png").into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Picasso` single instance only use load method multiple by passing different-different `imageview`, check below code :

```
Picasso mPicasso = Picasso.with(context);
mPicasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
mPicasso....load().into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!